# Using local storage of html5 to store a variable value

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I want to store a variable value permanantly so that i can have it even after closing the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Use browser localStorage, it stores data even after you close browser. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 1):

The simple example would be:
Saving to LocalStorage

```
localStorage.setItem('myKey', "This can be any value that I want");
```

Loading from localsotrage:

```
var tmp= localStorage.getItem('myKey');
```

You must know the key that you used for storing that data.

You should check when initializing the JS if localstorage is available, you can use the following function:

```
function checkLocalStorage() {
   var test = 'localStorageTestAvailability';
   try {
       localStorage.setItem(test, test);
       localStorage.removeItem(test);
       return true;
    } catch (e) {
       return false;
    }
};
```